# Difference in meaning between 'in view of' and 'in the view of'?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I wonder if 'in view of' or 'in **the** view of' have different meanings. For example, when I want to mention someone's opinion, e.g.

'In **the** view of Peter, doing X is a bad idea.' OR
'In view of Peter, doing X is a bad idea.'

Which one is correct? And can the other one still be used in other contexts?

Thanks for any input!

Comment: You would normally say "in Peter's opinion".

Comment: @MaxWilliams not if it is refering to something Peter can see.

Comment: @Helmar true, but when you talk about something being a "bad idea" it makes us think we're talking about **thoughts**.

Comment: @Helmar and this sort of usage is usually seen when "view" means "opinion" anyway, like "Well, my view on this is that we shouldn't get involved", for example.

Comment: @MaxWilliams you're right, and I just realized that it says opinion right there in the question. The punctuation doesn't make any sense with the _seeing_ meaning either.

Comment: @Helmar yes, the problem is that neither of the options are very idiomatic so we're left guessing to some extent.  (also, I didn't notice about opinion being mentioned either)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use the word view, instead of the better (in my opinion) "in Peter's opinion", then I think the closest idiomatic usage is

"Peter's view is that doing X is a bad idea".

Answer (score 1):

"In view of" is used to denote a relevant circumstance. It may be replaced by "Considering".  For example "In view of Peter's lack of experience, we should seek other opinions", or "In view of the financial restraints, we might have to abandon that idea".

Answer (score 1):

'In the view of Peter, doing X is a bad idea.' is far less idiomatic than

'In Peter's view, doing X is a bad idea.' (which is fine).

..................

'In view of Peter, doing X is a bad idea.' has a very different meaning, which might be paraphrased

'Doing X is not a good idea: think of the effect it would / might have on Peter.' or possibly 'Doing X is not a good idea: think of what happened to  Peter when *he* tried it.' But 'in view of' = 'in the light of' is usually used with an event, past or possible, as object, not a person.

Answer (score 0):

In view of> due to > In view of all that has happened, Conklin is expected to resign.

In the view of > according to sb > In THE view of the social liberals,...

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).